# Regex performance issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, timeout

I have to construct a regex for angularjs ng-pattern attribute. The regex has to validate a text, not each line or some pieces.
This is the format i have to validate: some text with spaces and punctuation:digits.2digits

For example this text is valid:

```
name:1234.32 name:234.43<br>
name:43.22
```

For example this text is not valid because one group starts with ":":

```
name:1234.32 :234.43<br>
name:43.22
```

For example this text is not valid because last group doesn't end with 2 decimals:

```
name:1234.32 name:234.43 name:43.2
```

I have build some regex but in case i have a bigger text, it fails with `timeout`. It fails only when last group is invalid. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/vsF98X/1/) is an example.
This is my regex:

```
^(([\S\s]+)\s*:\s*([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*)+$
```

Can you help me optimize this regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: This is not good. If my text is '1234:432.34       :432.34', it isn't valid because the second group(:432.34) starts with ':' and the text before ':' is required.

Comment: what the second `+` mean? check about https://regex101.com/r/I8TSGJ/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own regex has multiple following quantifiers with no limitation on matching characters that causes engine to encounter a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) almost on failure on large data.

You'd go with a regex like this:

```
^(([^:]*)\S\s*:\s*\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d))*$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JEpJ7J/2)

Breakdown:

```
^   # Assert beginning of input string
(   # Construct a group #1
    ([^:]*) # Construct group #2, match anything except `:`
    \S\s*:\s*\d+\.\d{2}(?!\d)   # Match a valid sequence
)*  # Repeat #1 as much as possible
$   # End of input string
```

Comment: Before and after ':' spaces are allowed. Olso, with your regex, if the last group has some spaces after, the text is not valid, and it should be. Thanks

Comment: If before colons spaces are allowed so why did you say `name:1234.32 :234.43<br>` should be invalid? You should be more precise about rules.

Comment: Because :234.43 doesn't have a name before ':'. To be valid it has to be like this: text with spaces  :   2234.43

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that it worked. You may accept this answer if it provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `^(([\S\s]+)\s*?:\s*?([0-9]+[.][0-9]{2})\s*?)+$`

But I recommend if you can, split text on lines and evaluate each one, and stop at line that not complain the test.